# How to change Div Id value when adding rows to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a problem and the solution to this problem is just a little bit beyond my programming ability... Hopefully someone can help me.

I have a table with a div inside each cell. I need the div id to dynamically change whenever a row or a column is added to the table. The div id's snake around the table, so when a new row or column is added, the div ids have to change. The div ids are used in the Javascript, so they have to dynamically change or the code won't work.

I created picture examples of everything, but since I'm a new member I can't add them. Hopefully my text example below will help you to see what I mean...

2X2 Table with div ids that snake back around:

| div id = 1 | div id = 2 |
| div id = 4 | div id = 3 |

2X3 table with a new column added with how the div ids need to look:

| div id = 1 | div id = 2 | div id = 3 |
| div id = 6 | div id = 5 | div id = 4 |

Also if you have another idea in mind of how this could work, let me know. I'm open to all suggestions.

Update...

I've added a jsfiddle with a small example of my code and how it's being used. At this point I'm thinking I have two options.

As you can see, The draggables drop in order or they revert, so one option is to change the way this is done.

My second option is what has been mentioned here a few times and change the way the div ties to the jQuery droppable code.

Hope this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/irocmon/wzb5U/

Comment: On a side note: an id attribute should not start with a numeral: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, why do you need the IDs? Also, how will the table columns be added?

Comment: @joseph for the reference it can in HTML5 I'm pretty sure http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: You mentioned that:

_"...when a new row or column is added, the div ids have to change. The div ids are used in the javascript, so they have to dynamically change or the code won't work."_

Why are you adding ids if they change? If all you're using them for is a hook for your javascript, there are better ways of accomplishing this. It's hard to advise alternatives without seeing the code and its purpose, though.

Comment: @Cubed Eye - Awesome! I didn't know that. I searched around, and it seems you're right: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: You are definitely going about this the wrong way. Since you are using jQuery, you can easily change your code to not depend on the ids at all.

Comment: It may well be that numeric IDs are valid in HTML 5 - but take a look at http://ishtml5readyyet.com/ (view the source too). On another note, you should use jQuery for this. It's slightly more complex than one that I've done but it is certainly feasible. What you do is, for every row, check the number of the row (see if it is odd or even) and, depending on which it is, loop through the cells from (start|finish) to (finish|start) and rename each div to something like "div_" + (row index x cell index).

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for all the comments and answers. I'd love to hear your ideas for tying the jQuery to the div, since that is all i'm using the div id for. Each div id ties to a jQuery droppable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just written a quick demo for you at http://jsfiddle.net/65Uwh/. It loops through all the rows, checks if it is odd or even and renames the IDs as appropriate (and sets the value of a span in each div so you can see the number).

You should be able to easily add a button which, on click, adds a row to a table which is an exact duplicate of, for example, the last row (using `$("tbody tr:last-child", $(this)).clone();`) and appends it to the `tbody`, then calls the function. Columns should be just as easy.

Comment: And ANOTHER drive-by downvote... what's wrong with my answer? It is perfectly valid and does pretty much everything I can get from the question..

Comment: Yeah, i don't know why you received a down vote. The example looks great! So... I'm trying to reference the div id in my javascript and css. I'm trying "div_1", "div_2", etc... but i can't seem to get it to reference. Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: No, it was my mistake. It was actually appending the row number to the cell number. I have added another set of brackets so that it adds the two together. Note that you will have to add something else into the ID to identify the table, if you have multiple tables. Currently that example outputs duplicate IDs but can be easily adjusted to take multiple tables into account.

Comment: Your code works great with those added brackets... Unforunately, i don't think jQuery works with div ids that are dynamically created. Like i said in the comment above. I'm using these ids to tie to jQuery droppables. I've tried your code and about 3 other things tonight, including using a createElement to create a div and for some reason if i create the div id dynamically with javascript the jQuery droppable doesn't work. Do you have any other ideas? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you paste your exact code above (or better still put it in a jsfiddle and link it here)? I think I know what's going on here...

Comment: Ok, sounds good. When i get a minute i'll create a jsfiddle and post it here. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok. I added an update to my post above with a jsfiddle with a small snippet of code.

Comment: not sure if this is the issue on your local site, but... you didn't include jQueryUI. It appears to be working perfectly once that is included.

Comment: I have updated my jsfiddle to incorporate draggables, but I have work in a few hours so not going to to droppables for you - besides I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve here. Perhaps you can expand on it? Anyway have a go at this until I get home from work and I'll see if I can help further.

Comment: Hello. So, the draggables are fine. The droppables are the issue. In my jsfiddle there are 4 droppables that you can see enable the next div id and disable themselves when dropped into. I just need that same idea no matter if the table is 2X2 or 20X20 in that snake pattern. I adjusted your jsfiddle and its really really close now... All that needs to be added is so they get enabled in order. And for some reason the jsQuery dialog box isn't working. Here it is.

Comment: Hello. So, the draggables are fine. The droppables are the issue. In my jsfiddle there are 4 droppables where the first one is enabled, then when you drop into it, the next div id get enabled and it disables itself, etc... I just need that same idea, no matter the size of the table, in that snake pattern. I adjusted your jsfiddle and its really really close now... All that needs to be added is that they get disabled and enabled in order. And for some reason the jsQuery dialog box isn't working. Here it is. Thank you so much!!! Ignore the comment above.. jsfiddle.net/irocmon/65Uwh/14

Comment: Ok. So got the dialog box to work just had to add the <p> tags. I knew that part wouldn't be too hard, just didn't have time to look at it. So just that one last thing of enabling the droppables in order and we are golden! Once again, thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: And I also was able to add into the code so the jQuery selector uses a counter variable to be able to enable the droppables in order. Thanks again for all your help! I will definitely mark yours as the answer, since your code works perfectly!!

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I didn't come back to have a go at this.. life got hectic for the past 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if i understood your question correctly but here's an example of which i came up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/zUdZR/2/

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><td><div></div></td><td><div></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td><div></div></td><td><div></div></td></tr>
</table>
<button id="r">add row</button><button id="c">add column</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    updateIDs();
    $('#r').click(function(){
        $('table').append($('table tr:last-child').clone());
        updateIDs();
    });

    $('#c').click(function(){
        $('table td:last-child').after('<td><div></div></td>');
        updateIDs();
    });


    function updateIDs(){
        $('div').each(function(i){
            var $d = $(this);
            var even = ($d.closest('tr').index()+1)%2==0;
            var tdl = $d.closest('tr').find('td').length;
            var tdi = $d.closest('td').index()+1;
            var id = i+1;
            id = even ?(id-tdi+1)-tdi+tdl:id;
            $(this).text(id);
        });   
    }
});
```